# DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet not exporting correctly

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm looking to export 2 worksheets (ACTIVITY & MASTERFILE) from Excel to Access using the AccountTable and ActivityTable using the AccountDoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet function.

My issue right now is that for some reason, it exports the contents of ACTIVITY to both tables in the Access database.

I've tried different methods such as activating MASTERFILE spreadsheet at the beginning of the Export sub and hiding ACTIVITY spreadsheet after it exports but it still exports the ACTIVITY content to both tables.

```
'exports the data from the spreadsheet to the Access database
Sub ExportMaster()

    'declaring our files, directories, tables and field names
    Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String, fileName As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
    Dim MasterDB As Worksheet
    
    'Declaring year value of 1 month & 2 month
    'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
    Year_1M = Format(Date - 27, "YYYY")

    'Declaring month value of 1 month & 2 month
    'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
    Month_1M = Format(Date - 27, "MM")

    'This translates the current month from number to character format
    MonthChar_1 = MonthName(Month_1M, False)
    
    sheet = "MASTERFILE_" & Year_1M & Month_1M
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    blnHasFieldNames = True
    
    strPath = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\"
    
    strTable = "AccountTable"
    
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "Monthly Reporting Tool.xlsm")
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, sheet
    
    
End Sub

'exports the data from the spreadsheet to the Access database
Sub ExportActivity()
    'declaring our files, directories, tables and field names
    Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String, fileName As String
    Dim strTable As String
    Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
    Dim MasterDB As Worksheet
    
    'Declaring year value of 1 month & 2 month
    'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
    Year_1M = Format(Date - 27, "YYYY")

    'Declaring month value of 1 month & 2 month
    'This is important to compare datasets from 2 months ago & last month
    Month_1M = Format(Date - 27, "MM")

    'This translates the current month from number to character format
    MonthChar_1 = MonthName(Month_1M, False)
    
    sheet = "ACTIVITY_" & Year_1M & Month_1M
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    blnHasFieldNames = True
    
    strPath = "Z:\Danny Tool Test Folder\"
    
    strTable = "ActivityTable"
    
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "Monthly Reporting Tool.xlsm")
      strPathFile = strPath & strFile
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, sheet
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are not specifying the sheet it is coming from.  This is after the has headers argument

Comment: Like so https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?660771-DoCmd-TransferSpreadsheet-acImport-In-Access

Comment: Got it. Thanks man!